# Overfull \hbox in subsection heading when using fontspec

Tags: sectioning, fontspec

In the following example I get an `Overfull \hbox` in the subsection heading when loading fontspec:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\@arabic\c@section}
\makeatother
\quarkmarks
\setpagecc{24.1cm}{16.4cm}{*}
\settypeblocksize{*}{11.8cm}{*}
\setlrmargins{2.1cm}{*}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{2.1cm}{2.5cm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
\setsecnumdepth{paragraph} 
\setsubsecheadstyle{\bfseries}
%\setsubsecheadstyle{\bfseries\raggedright}
\setaftersubsecskip{1sp}
\setsecnumformat{\csname my#1\endcsname}
\newcommand{\mysubsection}{\thesubsection\qquad}

\begin{document}
\subsection{Places: River Banks, Charnel Grounds and Other Shared Locations}
%\subsection[Places: River Banks, Charnel Grounds and Other Shared Locations]{Places: River Banks, Charnel Grounds and Other\\ Shared Locations}
\end{document}
```

with fontspec:

[image: fontspec loaded]

with fontspec commented out:

[image: without fontspec]

It seems that without fontspec the permitted inter word space is higher. How can I get the same output using fontspec?

Comment: The fonts are different; it's apparently a tough situation where even small differences in the letter widths and in the spacing parameters make XeTeX into not being able to set the title when Latin Modern (OpenType) is used. If you plan to have long titles, it's better to use `\raggedright` anyway.